# Close icon popover on outside click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have an icon that has a popover.

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="popover" aria-hidden="true" title="More Info" data-content="..."></i>
```

The popover works fine. I am trying to get it to close when the user clicks anywhere else on the page. I have found tutorials that use "focus". However it is not working, I believe it is because I am calling the popover on an icon and focus is used on buttons? I guess... Anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> just use **data-trigger="focus"**

or

```
$('.popover-dismiss').popover({
  trigger: 'focus'
})
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script  src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?" data-trigger="focus"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></button>
```

Comment: Did not work...Does it make a difference if my icon is in a modal?

Comment: yes , you have added data- attributes in your icon , i have added in button

Comment: I got it to work when I wrap it in a button but I just want the icon. Is it possible to do it without wrapping the icon in a button?